# Testing React form input value changes with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I've been working on this test for a while now and although I can find several solutions online I cannot find anything that will work for me. I want to check if the displayed text in an input field is updating when the `onChange` function is used.  I do not want to test state directly.

I have a form with the following state and change handling function:

```
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    createFirstName: '',
    createLastName: '',
    createEmail: '',
    createJobTitle: '',
    createWorkPhone: '',
    createCellPhone: '',
    createExtension: '',
  });

  const handleChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      [event.target.name]: value
    });
  };
```

Pretty standard so far.  I also have a form with the following input field:

```
<input
   name="createFirstName"
   id="assign-role-form-first-name-input"
   onChange={handleChange}
   type="text"
   ref={register({ required: true })}
   defaultValue={""}
            />
```

Now I should mention I am using `react-hook-form` which helps with form validations although I don't think that would cause an issue.

I am trying to write a test that triggers the input value to change.  I have tried many different combinations of things such as:

```
it('Should capture firstname correctly onChange', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<AssignRoleForm />);
    const input = wrapper.find('#assign-role-form-first-name-input')
    input.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Goose'}});
    expect(input.props()).toEqual('Goose')
})
```

or

```
it('Should capture firstname correctly onChange', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<AssignRoleForm />);
    const input = wrapper.find('#assign-role-form-first-name-input')
    input.simulate('change', {target: {name: 'createFirstName' value: 'Goose'}});
    expect(input.prop('value')).toEqual('Goose')
})
```

I have also tried setting the prop using

```
input.prop('onChange')({target: {value: 'Goose'}})
```

I have tried using `act(() => {}` as well as other combinations of the above.  I also tried getting rid of `defaultValue` on the input field and using `value` instead but this did not work either. I am not sure if my issue is in updating the input or if it is in the way I am calling the input.

Comment: How are you passing the current value to the `assign-role-form-first-name-input` input? In your code, it seems that you are updating the `state` with the form values, but you are not passing those values to the inputs (at least, not for `assign-role-form-first-name-input`).

Comment: @mgarcia That is correct.  I am not passing values back to the input, I believe that is handled by the form.  Still when I fill in the input forms I am able to see the text appear in the input so this should be testable.

Comment: Mmm, I'm not so sure about that. If you don't provide a value attribute to the component in React, your React application is not the one that is setting the value. Instead, the input works as an uncontrolled component and it is the HTML Element who is showing the value as you type characters in it.

Comment: @tdammon did you figure this out? struggling with the same thing, and don't want to switch to react-testing-library only for this

Comment: I'm also dead in the water with this problem ...

Comment: It's actually still relatable. I've found out that actually input value change is trigerred on blur, but simulating it still doesn't solve the problem. Probably regarding opened issues on library testing works fine with react-testing-library